# Flyout changes Page's theme

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm fighting with little problem on WP8.1 - it took some time, but finally I've managed to localize it - let say that we have a button with a flyout:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="reset" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout Placement="Top">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="first item"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="second item"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

It works fine, but if we set the `DataContext` of a page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this; // without this works fine every button click
}
```

then there is a problem - the first time we click our button - works fine, but when we click it the second time, along with flyout, the page's theme changes to *Light* (the changed theme persists after we dismiss the flyout, you will have to reload the page). It looks more or less like in the images below:

[image][image]

Does anybody know what can cause the problem? Any workarounds?

If somebody wants to try - [here is a sample code](http://1drv.ms/1qh3SJJ).

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I've run into what seems like the same issue in Windows 8.1. I worked around by using ThemeResources and setting the RequestedTheme for the FlyoutStyle to Dark for default theme, and Light for the light theme, then I overrode the other properties as needed.  Not completely vetted at this point though.

Comment: @JimO'Neil No, it seems to be a bug and I haven't found workaround. For now I've replaced flyout with popup - in my case it was quite simple and doesn't affect UI much. I hope this will be corrected in W10.

Comment: It is NOT corrected in W10. Same problem with flyout under AppBarButton. But when I set theme to AppBarButton, flyout is changed also.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Sorry for late reply - I was on small holiday. Thanks for this information. I'll give you some more info once I make some tests (this can take a while). Thanks.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Hmm. On what knd of project have you checked this under W10m? As I've tried on UWP it seems to work now.

Comment: The same with W8.1 app running on W10. The solution of the_nuts works. Thank you for the question.  The app allows its users to change the theme, but they have to restart the app for the theme to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it's happening, but you can force your page's RequestedTheme when the page is loaded:

XAML

```
<Page
...
x:Name="myPage">
```

C#

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    if (App.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
    {
        myPage.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    }
    else
    {
        myPage.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, hence the issue seems to disappear when you force the theme. But it's not the solution I'm looking for - I don't want to force the theme, this will fail if the user changes the theme while the app is running.