# Button with flyout change apperance of other buttons when clicked - Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows 8.1 project i have the following button with a flyout.

```
 <Button x:Name="FilterCompanyMeetings2" Foreground="White" Content="Company Meetings" Margin="15,58,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle2}">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout>
                        <StackPanel Width="406">
                            <TextBlock Text="Insert the value and tap the Send button:" FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="SemiLight" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       Margin="0,0,0,10"  />
                            <TextBox x:Name="ValueTextBox" />
                            <Button Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
```

Im having a issue when i press the button, the flyout appears as expected but all other buttons change their background to a gray color and some of them change their foreground to black.

I dont use this button for anything at the moment, but when i press it that happens.

Why does it change style of other button on the page?

Comment: Once [I've observed similar thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25529624/2681948) on Windows Phone 8.1, so this may be related. As I've tested the issue seems to be fixed on W10 UWP.